# Display radiobuttons and labels in a row

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this piece of code in my view:

```
<div class=" col-md-12" style="margin: 0 auto;">
 <p>Male</p>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale,"false", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
 <p>Female</p>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "true", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsFemale, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

 </div>
```

I would like some tips on how to display all this info in one row, like this:

```
Male x Female y.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `<p>` tags to `<label>` tags. `<p>` tags are block elements so the radio buttons will be pushed onto a new line, `<label>` tags are inline so the radio buttons would be kept on the same line.

```
<div class=" col-md-12" style="margin: 0 auto;">
 <label>Male</label>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale,"false", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
 <label>Female</label>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "true", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsFemale, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be relatively new to `ASP.NET MVC`, and are making use of `razor` syntax, I'd suggest you to take advantage of the razor's syntax to achieve what you are looking for. There is an html helper provided by razor for displaying just that:**`labels`**. Here's the way you'd use it:

```
<div class=" col-md-12" style="margin: 0 auto;">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsFemale, "Female")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale,"false", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsFemale, "Male")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "true", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsFemale, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

`.col-md-12 p {display:inline;padding:0;margin:0;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/wildandjam/aguUF/

Comment: Nuke ALL the `<p>` tags!

Comment: More specificity added.